# vb.net Emails sent and received but no attachments

Tags: vb.net, email, attachment, email-attachments

I have a page where emails can be sent with multiple attachments. Here is my code to upload files through asp:AjaxFileUpload control called `ajaxUpload1`:

```
Protected Sub ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs)

    Dim filePath As String = "~/Uploads/" & Convert.ToString(e.FileName)

    ' Save upload file to the file system
    ajaxUpload1.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath))

    e.PostedUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~\uploads\" + e.FileName)
    Try
        emailAttachment = New System.Net.Mail.Attachment(filePath)
        attahchemnts.Add(emailAttachment)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Label2.Text = ex.ToString
    End Try


End Sub
```

`attahchemnts` is a list consisting of all uploaded files names.

And this bit is responsible to set mail attachments at button click event

```
Try
            If ajaxUpload1.HasAttributes Then

                For counter As Integer = 0 To attahchemnts.Count
                    mail.Attachments.Add(attahchemnts.Item(counter))

                Next

            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Label2.Text = ex.ToString
        End Try
```

The issue is that I am able to send and receive emails successfully, but I can't see email attachments. Any one has a clue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the C# version of how I successfully do it

```
 var m = new MailMessage { Subject = txtSubject.Text, IsBodyHtml = true, Body = emailOpeningLine + txtMessage.Text };

            try
            {
                m.To.Add(new MailAddress(dr[0].ToString().Trim()));
                m.From = new MailAddress(txtUserName.Text);
                foreach (var attachment in Attactments)
                {
                    m.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(attachment));
                }
                client.Send(m);
                m.To.Clear();
                m.Attachments.Clear();
                Success.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            }
            catch (SmtpException esException)
            {
                Errors.Add("Error sending to " + dr[0].ToString() + " " + esException.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Errors.Add("Error sending to " + dr[0].ToString() + " " + ex.Message);

            }
```

In this example I have a list of string with the locations of the attachments that is loops through to add to the Mail Message.

I also have a success and fail list too so that it continues on a fail and then i pick up any errors afterwards.

You should be able convert this using telerik code converter